# Why can't I simply prepend text?

Tags: jquery

While answering a question I faced some problem. I was trying to prepend simply the text but couldn't.

```
<div>
    <span>some</span>
</div>
```

should result in

```
<div>prepended text here
    <span>some</span>
</div>
```

These don't work:

```
$('div').prepend('prepended text here');
$('div').prepend(html('prepended text here'));
$('div').prepend(text('prepended text here'));
```

So, how can I simply prepend the text only?

---

**Update:**

oh! sorry that's working but see this http://jsfiddle.net/Znsj8/1/

```
$('.booktext').contents().filter(function(){
return this.nodeType !== 1;
}).remove().prepend('your text');
```

it's not working!

Comment: It works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/6a6Fx/

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: Welcome on SO! ;) Could you tell us what means 'don't work'?

Comment: Of course, [prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) is just not designed to accept plain text. But it definitively accepts HTML.

Comment: Please check the updated one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are removing elements and then targeting them using prepend. You can't prepend content to no more existing element. Target again the content of the DIV, using `end()`:

[DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Znsj8/2/)

```
var ur_text = "your text";
$('.booktext').contents().filter(function(){
     return this.nodeType !== 1;
}).remove().end().prepend('your text');
```

Comment: um... that was it. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can only prepend on a jQuery object that references a DOM element. Apart from that, if you prepend to something that has been removed, you won't see any effect anyway. If you `get(0)` the text node, you can change the content of it:

```
var ur_text = "your text";
$('.booktext').contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType !== 1;
}).get(0).textContent = ur_text;
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Znsj8/3/)